# Karaf 4.0.8 Mysql Db Access

Tags: karaf

I have created data source as below in separate bundle and installed

```
<blueprint><bean id="dataSource class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/cns"/>
<property name="user" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
<service-properties><entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/mysqlds"/></service-properties>
</service>
</blueprint>
```

Installed the paj-mysql drvier.I am injecting datasource in other bundle ,still not able to create a connnection ,from log i am seeing injection is sucessful .during get connection i am getting null pointer

```
<bean id="ex" class="com.example.dbexample.Ex" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```